# CodeIgniter 4 routes not working properly

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just got into CI4 from a CI3 background but I'm finding it difficult to get routes to display the appropriate view. Even though I have written the code in the controller properly to load a view, it always returns index.php no matter what instead of the correct view even when I enter a non-existent route. The 404 page doesn't show either.

Here's my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Shop extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('shop');
    }
}
```

Here's the result I get on the browser:
[image: Result]

Comment: Have you tried `echo view('shop');`? You should not return it : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#view

Comment: It doesn't work either. I noticed the page still renders index.php even for non-existent routes instead of showing the 404 page.

Comment: @VilLar yes he can return the view. In CI 4 you can do both. When you download ci4 the default view is returned not echoed. https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/4.1/app/Controllers/Home.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED!

I realized the problem was that apache's rewrite module was disabled by default by running `sudo a2query -m rewrite` so I had to enable it by running `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. If you're having this same issue please make sure your rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: Or in case you're not able to enable mod_rewrite on your server for some reason, just remove the .htaccess that comes with codeigniter and make sure your app is configured to use the index.php file. https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Config/App.php#L39 That way you dont need mod_rewrite but your urls would look like foo.com/index.php/controller/method/param